# Spring - Merge multiple properties from a single file into List<String>

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to merge multiple configuration properties into a single List of Strings?

Lets say I want to configure supported extensions, like this:

```
application.extension.pdf=pdf
application.extension.txt=txt
application.extension.docx=docx
```

And at runtime, it loads like this:

```
List<String> extensions = {"pdf","txt","docx"}
```

And then I can check if the list contains some extension.
A Set could work too.

Comment: Why not like `application.extension=pdf,txt,docx`?

Comment: Your proposal is under my consideration, but it will be the last call. I prefer to stick whit the first approach, even if it requires more code, in order to make the configuration more intuitive and easy to read.

Comment: Well, AFAIK you would need 1 property which includes all the values. Else you would read every configuration on its own and construct the list during runtime with all the single configurations. This would need to be updated as soon as a new configuration is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bean which does the load for you and fills a map with the properties.

PropertyFile:

```java
application.extensions.map.pdf=pdf
application.extensions.map.txt=txt
application.extensions.map.docx=docx
```

Bean:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("application.extensions")
public class ExtensionMapper {
    private Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}
```

This may be usefull in mapping context, where you need key and value.

(Be aware of the updated property path)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a file called *supported_extensions.props* in a folder of your choice having the content you posted. Then you can read the lines of the file, split them by `"="` and take the last part of the resulting array, which is the extension itself. Try these lines of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filePathString = "Y:\\our\\folder\\supported_extensions.props";
    Path filePath = Paths.get(filePathString);
    List<String> extensionProperties = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        extensionProperties = Files.readAllLines(filePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<String> extensions = new ArrayList<>();

    extensionProperties.forEach(extensionProperty -> {
        String extension = extensionProperty.split("=")[1];
        extensions.add(extension);
    });

    extensions.forEach(extension -> {
        System.out.println(extension);
    });
}
```

You have to include these imports to make it work:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

> Consider the hint(s) given in the comments below your question, they are not unimportant!